# How to display tweets from a twitter account and tweet that same account from an android app using twitter4j?

Tags: java, android, twitter

I'm currently trying to make an app that should pull the last 10 or 20 tweets from a twitter account (not mine, but a third party), and display them. I also want to be able to let user's post a tweet to this person and follow them on twitter if they don't already.

I've been looking at tutorials the last few hours and really cannot wrap my head around it. I've already imported the twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar into my project.

In my MainActivity.java, I have a method that responds to a button:

---

```
public void twitter(View view) 
{
    //Create an intent and send it the twitter activity class
    Intent twitterActivity = new Intent(this, TwitterActivity.class);
    startActivity(twitterActivity);
}
```

---

So what I want to know is, how do I set up the view to display the tweets from the a twitter account, as well as allow a user to tweet them, and/or follow them.

This is what I have so far in my TwitterActivity.java:

---

```
import java.util.List;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class TwitterActivity extends Activity 
{

// I think I need to create some global variables here for the consumer key and consumer secret.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter);

        setupActionBar();

        // I assume the twitter set up happens here.

    }

.....

}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you will have to use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` to get it work.

Use this uri to get the tweets:

> http://api.tweeter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=

Also tweets can be obtained from using following code:

```
new Read().execute("text")
```

where `text` has the actual tweet.

You can then use StringBuilder and append the username to the URI as mentioned above.

Comment: Nice first post! Welcome to Stack Overflow.